# Some Products in ebay api do not return pictureURLLarge for product listing using findItemsAdvanced

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am new to ebay API. I am trying to call a service from ebay as shown below

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?
OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&
SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&
SECURITY-APPNAME=XXXXXXXX&
GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-IN&outputSelector=PictureURLLarge&
RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD
```

I have already added the `outputSelector=PictureURLLarge`. But some products returned do not receive the `pictureURLLarge`

The following is the output of one of the `SimpleXMLElement`  I am getting,

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
     ............... 
     ...............
    [galleryURL] => http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mul3eDNEoMQ0GzjE_L86YtA/80.jpg
    [viewItemURL] => http://www.ebay.in/itm/Nike-Golf-Sport-Shoe-Tote-/290867798430?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203
    [paymentMethod] => PaisaPayEscrow
    [autoPay] => false
    [location] => India
    [country] => IN
    [shippingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [shippingServiceCost] => 0.0
            [shippingType] => Free
            [shipToLocations] => IN
        )

    [sellingStatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [currentPrice] => 3540.0
            [convertedCurrentPrice] => 3540.0
            [sellingState] => Active
            [timeLeft] => P26DT3H27M13S
        )

    [listingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [bestOfferEnabled] => false
            [buyItNowAvailable] => false
            [startTime] => 2013-02-21T18:09:53.000Z
            [endTime] => 2013-09-19T18:14:53.000Z
            [listingType] => StoreInventory
            [gift] => false
        )

    [condition] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [conditionId] => 1000
            [conditionDisplayName] => New
        )

    [isMultiVariationListing] => false
    [topRatedListing] => false
)
```

If we check the link where the product is, that is **viewItemURL** [here](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Nike-Golf-Sport-Shoe-Tote-/290867798430?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203), we are been displayed a Large Image, but here we are not getting the same in **PictureURLLarge**.

Is there any other way to do this?

Any help would be appreciable.

**Note** : I do not want to use the GetSingleItem, that would result in lots of api calls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? :\

Comment: Nope, I did not get it still. :(
But we used something else to solve the problem.